# What is $\alpha = m\angle CDE$?

Tags: geometry

[image]

$$m\angle EBC = 50° $$
$$m\angle ABE  = 30° $$
$$m\angle DCB = 60° $$
$$m\angle ACD = 20° $$

- What is  $\alpha = m\angle CDE$?

It seems a bit confused. Where should I start from?

Regards